# How to draw minor gridlines between major gridlines?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to draw minor gridlines in the center between major gridlines.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 4;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 3;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.Cornsilk;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle= ChartDashStyle.Solid;
```

I tried to set different values of chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval but didn't get expected result.Here what I got so far.
[image: Arrow points to right located minor gridline]
Arrow points to right located minor gridline
I tried to change chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset property but it does not change anything. Has someone any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
Based on TaW's answer tried to set intervals

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 4;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 2;
```

got 
[image]

**EDIT 2**

It was a good idea proposed by TaW, but since for me was not important LineDashStyle and custom labels are used, I decided to abandon minor lines and instead use major lines and custom labels, plotted for each second line.
Issue resolved

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `MinorGrid` lines **centered** between the `MajorGrid` their `Interval` ought to be **half** their value:

```
Axix ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.MajorGrid.Interval = 4;
ax.MinorGrid.Interval = ax.MajorGrid.Interval / 2;
```

If you want more  `MinorGrid` lines the  `MajorGrid.Interval` still should be divisible by `MinorGrid.Interval`.

In case you really want to set an `Offset`, both should have the same !

Since your `X-Values` are `DateTimes`, you also will want to control the `IntervalTypes`:

```
ax.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
ax.MinorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
```

**Note** that, as usual, every other major line overwrites a minor one. If this is a problem you can make the `Intervals` the same and offset one by **half** an `Interval`; but normally it will not matter.
[image]

Comment: See the updated answer. (My screenshot uses a different styling..)

Comment: I need minor gridlines will not binded to IntervalType, because labels are shifted relatively gridlines like in your example.

Comment: Well, they still __do have__ an `IntervalType` which will determine just what the `Interval` etc will mean... To control the `Labels` you can use the respective properties: `ax.LabelStyle.IntervalType, ax.LabelStyle.Interval, ax.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset`.